# TestingAuthenticationToken and @PreAuthorizedTest -anotation ignored

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have following test-config.xml

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="testProvider" /> 
    <authentication-provider> 
        <user-service>
            <user name="department1000" password="password" authorities="ROLE_1000" />
            <user name="user"    password="password2" authorities="ROLE_ALL_DEPT_ACCESS" />
            <user name="user1"    password="password3" authorities="ROLE_STUDENT" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="testProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationProvider">
</beans:bean>
```

I need a method that simulates authentication and giving the role:

```
protected void simulateRole(String role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    token = new TestingAuthenticationToken("username","password", authorities);
       securityContext.setAuthentication((getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token)));
```

Then I need to call the @PreAuthorized anotated controller method for test:

```
@Test(expected = AccessDeniedException.class)
public void testShowAccessDenied() {
    super.simulateRole("ROLE_STUDENT");
    controller.show(new ModelMap(), super.getAuthenticationPrincipal(), Locale.getDefault(), new D(), new E());
    super.getSecurityContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
```

I think I'm not setting the required Principal right, since test is not throwing AccessDeniedException

```
    public Principal getAuthenticationPrincipal() {
    return (Principal) securityContext.getAuthentication().getDetails();
```

Changing the type of controller method arguments would cause a lot of mess. Any way to get this working?

Comment: Why are you getting the principal as such securityContext.getAuthentication().getDetails();. Can you not just change it to be securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

Comment: Because that is not supported since the controller method requires Principal, not Object. Tried that. However, I don't think this is the reason why the anotation is ingnored.

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing the [global method security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-method-security) from your configuration. You should add the following to test-config.xml:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

**NOTE**: For this to work in a servlet environment, you need to ensure to add the global-method-security tag to your DispatcherServlet config and not the root configuration as [described in the FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context)

I'm assuming your controller does not implement an interface, so you will need to ensure that you have cglib on your classpath to support class based proxies. If you are using [Spring 4.x+ you can add objenesis to your classpath](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_core_container_improvements) and your proxied classes no longer need default constructors.

Second you need to ensure the controller in your test was created by Spring. When Spring creates the controller it uses the information from  to proxy the class and add the security to it.

If you are still having issues, please post your complete test that fails, the method you are testing on the controller, and complete test code.

Comment: I have global-method security in my xml first, but it does not show even thought I edit. Can someone fix it?

Comment: How are you creating your controller? As I mentioned previously you need to ensure it is created by Spring.